# Input **nil** into the function swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Supposed I have function:

```
cornerRadiusView(image, value:avalue, borderColor: color, borderWidth: avalue, isNeedBorder: false)
```

And sometimes when call this function I want to input **nil** for the fields which I not use. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a function like this

```
cornerRadiusView(image, value:avalue, borderColor: nil, borderWidth: avalue, isNeedBorder: false)
```

In it anything that can be nil should be an `Optional` parameter, denoted by `?`.

So it's function would look like

```
func cornerRadiusView(image: UIImage, borderColor: UIColor?, isNeedBorder: Bool)
```

An excerpt from [Apple's Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html)

> Swift also introduces
>   optional types, which handle the absence of a value. Optionals say
>   either “there is a value, and it equals x” or “there isn’t a value at
>   all”. Optionals are similar to using nil with pointers in Objective-C,
>   but they work for any type, not just classes. Optionals are safer and
>   more expressive than nil pointers in Objective-C and are at the heart
>   of many of Swift’s most powerful features.
>
> Optionals are an example of the fact that Swift is a type safe
>   language. Swift helps you to be clear about the types of values your
>   code can work with. If part of your code expects a String, type safety
>   prevents you from passing it an Int by mistake. This restriction
>   enables you to catch and fix errors as early as possible in the
>   development process.